# C# (.NET) handling Javascript Array/Serialization

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I'm using tableDnD to re-order table rows, and then serialize them using "$.tableDnD.serialize()"

I want to send this to C# for processing, what's the best of doing so?

The below is an example of the serialization

```
pages[]=&pages[]=21&pages[]=23&pages[]=34&pages[]=37&pages[]=40&pages[]=43&pages[]=46&pages[]=49&pages[]=31&pages[]=50&pages[]=51&pages[]=52&pages[]=53&pages[]=54&pages[]=55&pages[]=56&pages[]=57&pages[]=58&pages[]=61&pages[]=65&pages[]=70&pages[]=74&pages[]=77&pages[]=78&pages[]=79&pages[]=82&pages[]=85&pages[]=88&pages[]=91&pages[]=94&pages[]=97&pages[]=100&pages[]=103&pages[]=106&pages[]=109&pages[]=112&pages[]=115&pages[]=119&pages[]=122&pages[]=123
```

Important Information
**I tagged this as MVC but forgot to mention it. I'm using ASP.NET MVC**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can send that as-is using one of jQuery's ajax methods. I would prefer to turn it into a smaller, neater CSV string before sending it to the server as follows:

```
var str = 'pages[]=&pages[]=21&pages[]=23&pages[]=34&pages[]=37&pages[]=40&pages[]=43&pages[]=46&pages[]=49&pages[]=31&pages[]=50&pages[]=51&pages[]=52&pages[]=53&pages[]=54&pages[]=55&pages[]=56&pages[]=57&pages[]=58&pages[]=61&pages[]=65&pages[]=70&pages[]=74&pages[]=77&pages[]=78&pages[]=79&pages[]=82&pages[]=85&pages[]=88&pages[]=91&pages[]=94&pages[]=97&pages[]=100&pages[]=103&pages[]=106&pages[]=109&pages[]=112&pages[]=115&pages[]=119&pages[]=122&pages[]=123';

var tmpArr = str.split('&');
var pagesArr = [];
for(var i = 0;i < tmpArr.length; i++) {
    var paramArr = tmpArr[i].split('=');
    if(paramArr[1] != null && paramArr[1] != '') {
        pagesArr.push(paramArr[1]);
    }
}
alert(pagesArr); //now much prettier

//turn it into a CSV string
var pagesCsv = pagesArr.join(',');

$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "some.aspx",
   data: pagesCsv,
   success: function(msg){
     alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
   }
 });
```

Comment: I'm simply posting it, I can receive that string in C#, what I'm wondering is if there's a way to interpret it as an array in c# like you can do in PHP like for example http://www.isocra.com/articles/ajaxTest_php.html

Comment: @Shahin - I'm not sure as I'm not a ASP.NET guy, but you can send that string to the server and then convert it into an array by splitting it at the comma ','

Answer (score 0):

Based on the example of [karim79](https://stackoverflow.com/users/70393/karim79) :

```
var str = 'pages[]=&pages[]=21&pages[]=23&pages[]=34&pages[]=37&pages[]=40&pages[]=43&pages[]=46&pages[]=49&pages[]=31&pages[]=50&pages[]=51&pages[]=52&pages[]=53&pages[]=54&pages[]=55&pages[]=56&pages[]=57&pages[]=58&pages[]=61&pages[]=65&pages[]=70&pages[]=74&pages[]=77&pages[]=78&pages[]=79&pages[]=82&pages[]=85&pages[]=88&pages[]=91&pages[]=94&pages[]=97&pages[]=100&pages[]=103&pages[]=106&pages[]=109&pages[]=112&pages[]=115&pages[]=119&pages[]=122&pages[]=123';

var pos = null;
var index = 0;

while ((pos=str.indexOf("[]"))>-1)
{
    str = str.substr(0, pos-1) + "_" + (index) + str.substr(pos+2);
    index++;
}

alert(str);


$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "some.aspx",
   data: str,
   success: function(msg){
     alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
   }
 });
```

In C#

```
        string[] keys = Request.QueryString.AllKeys;
        Array.Sort(keys);

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (string key in keys)
        {
            if (key.IndexOf("pages_")!=-1)
            {
                sb.Append(Request.QueryString[key]);
            }
        }

        // sb container the all values
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also put everything in to one object like this:

```
var prm = { pages=[...], someOtherPages=[], additionalParam="", integer=1324 }
jQuery.ajax({
    url: "someurl.aspx",
    type: "POST",
    data: {prm: JSON.stringify(prm)},
    });
```

and parse prm on C# side by using [this JSON Parser](http://james.newtonking.com/pages/json-net.aspx):

```
JObject json = JObject.Parse(Request.Form["prm"]);
JArray items = json["pages"] as JArray;
foreach (JToken item in items)
{
   int i = item["type"].Value<int>(); // take an item as int
   string s = item["type"].Value<string>(); // take an item as string
   JArray ar = item["complex"] as JArray; // that an item as an array
}
```

much simplier and flexible

Comment: I like the look of this solution, thanks I'm going to give this a go now